# SQL Server grab data for multiple rows from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So here's the two tables I'm working with

StockItem:

```
ItemID               SKU                           MSKU
-------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------
36414                SWR0060                        
14859140             4220.12.010                    220.12.010
14860211             6220.12.010                    220.12.010
47717413             6000.22.010                    6000.22.XXX
102244764            SWR-SPIGOT                     SWR-SPIGOTS
115377648            SWR-SPIGOTBLA                  SWR-SPIGOTS
115381142            SWR-SPIGOTCOP                  SWR-SPIGOTS
116112478            6000.22.030                    6000.22.XXX
116112701            6000.22.050                    6000.22.XXX
119263276            SWR-SPIGOTAG                   SWR-SPIGOTS
```

StockItemMemo:

```
ItemID               MemoText
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
36414                Title:Professional C7 Steel Wire Rope Cutters (0.5mm - 4mm) Snips Fence Tool
14859140             Title:Stainless Steel Base Plate for 42.4mm Balustrade Handrail Railing Component
47717413             Title:52mm Stainless Glass Adapter (10-20mm) - Metric and Wood Thread Balustrade Handrail
102244764            Title:Stainless Steel Spigot 10-12mm Glass Handrail Balustrade Railing Balcony Clamp
```

Currently, when I run the query below, the title is displayed for the primary items which have the title directly joined to them, but the items joined to those items by the MSKU field show NULLs

```sql
DECLARE @title as VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Title:';

SELECT
ItemID,
Code as SKU, 
AnalysisCode12 as MSKU,
(SELECT TOP 1 MemoText FROM StockItemMemo WHERE StockItemMemo.ItemID = StockItem.ItemId and MemoText like @title+'%') as Title
From StockItem WHERE AnalysisCode7 = 'YES'
```

```
ItemID               SKU                            MSKU                                                         Title
-------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------
36414                SWR0060                                                                                     Professional C7 Steel Wire Rope Cutters (0.5mm - 4mm) Snips Fence Tool
14859140             4220.12.010                    220.12.010                                                   Stainless Steel Base Plate for 42.4mm Balustrade Handrail Railing Component
14860211             6220.12.010                    220.12.010                                                   NULL
47717413             6000.22.010                    6000.22.XXX                                                  52mm Stainless Glass Adapter (10-20mm) - Metric and Wood Thread Balustrade Handrail
102244764            SWR-SPIGOT                     SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  Stainless Steel Spigot 10-12mm Glass Handrail Balustrade Railing Balcony Clamp
115377648            SWR-SPIGOTBLA                  SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  NULL
115381142            SWR-SPIGOTCOP                  SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  NULL
116112478            6000.22.030                    6000.22.XXX                                                  NULL
116112701            6000.22.050                    6000.22.XXX                                                  NULL
119263276            SWR-SPIGOTAG                   SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  NULL
```

I need the title from the main SKU to show for all the items with a matching MSKU too, so the below is the result I want:

```
ItemID               SKU                            MSKU                                                         Title
-------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------
36414                SWR0060                                                                                     Professional C7 Steel Wire Rope Cutters (0.5mm - 4mm) Snips Fence Tool
14859140             4220.12.010                    220.12.010                                                   Stainless Steel Base Plate for 42.4mm Balustrade Handrail Railing Component
14860211             6220.12.010                    220.12.010                                                   Stainless Steel Base Plate for 42.4mm Balustrade Handrail Railing Component
47717413             6000.22.010                    6000.22.XXX                                                  52mm Stainless Glass Adapter (10-20mm) - Metric and Wood Thread Balustrade Handrail
102244764            SWR-SPIGOT                     SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  Stainless Steel Spigot 10-12mm Glass Handrail Balustrade Railing Balcony Clamp
115377648            SWR-SPIGOTBLA                  SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  Stainless Steel Spigot 10-12mm Glass Handrail Balustrade Railing Balcony Clamp
115381142            SWR-SPIGOTCOP                  SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  Stainless Steel Spigot 10-12mm Glass Handrail Balustrade Railing Balcony Clamp
116112478            6000.22.030                    6000.22.XXX                                                  52mm Stainless Glass Adapter (10-20mm) - Metric and Wood Thread Balustrade Handrail
116112701            6000.22.050                    6000.22.XXX                                                  52mm Stainless Glass Adapter (10-20mm) - Metric and Wood Thread Balustrade Handrail
119263276            SWR-SPIGOTAG                   SWR-SPIGOTS                                                  Stainless Steel Spigot 10-12mm Glass Handrail Balustrade Railing Balcony Clamp
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve your desired output using a query like below

```
DECLARE @title as VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Title:';



; WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 
    AnalysisCode12 as MSKU,
    MemoText as Title
FROM StockItemMemo SIM
  JOIN StockItem SI
    ON SIM.ItemID = SI.ItemId
WHERE MemoText like @title+'%'
)

SELECT
  ItemID,
  Code as SKU, 
  AnalysisCode12 as MSKU,
  C.Title
From StockItem SI
  LEFT JOIN CTE C 
    ON C.MSKU=SI.AnalysisCode12
WHERE AnalysisCode7 = 'YES'
```